# Libgdx FreeTypeFontGenerator not working on android?

Tags: java, android, fonts, libgdx, freetype

Although you probably already know this, i'm working with Java/Libgdx. I'm also running Ubuntu 12.04 with Eclipse, if that means anything.

I did some research on this and some people were having the same problem, but got a different error. I tried their solutions anyways, but to no avail.

Anyhow, my problem is that although my loading of freetypefonts works perfectly on my desktop
project, every time I try to compile the android project into an apk in eclipse, it comes up
with a weird error about dex loading or something. What could this be? I followed [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3JgjFZFQu74) tutorial perfectly.

This is the error I get when I try to compile it-

```
[2014-01-11 12:13:49 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/freetype/FreeType$Pointer;
[2014-01-11 12:14:08 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/freetype/FreeType$Pointer;
[2014-01-11 18:08:48 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/freetype/FreeType$Pointer;
[2014-01-11 18:12:16 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/freetype/FreeType$Pointer;
[2014-01-11 18:12:37 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/freetype/FreeType$Pointer;
```

Should I try Hiero or the likes of something else instead?

Answer (score 4):

You have that particular class duplicated. It seems you are adding the jars twice.

Right click your Android Project -> Properties -> Java Build path -> Order and Export tab, and check you aren't adding a jar twice, try unchecking private libraries.

Comment: Thanks, now it's compiling at least, but now when I run it on the emulator, it just suddenly force-closes. Any thoughts? All I did was uncheck gdx-freetype.jar under my android project, as it was already checked under my main one. Is that what you meant?

Comment: "The application MyLibgdxGame (process com.ashwin.timedestiny) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again." with a force close button

Comment: Any help anyone? Any thoughts @Lestat

Comment: @AshwinKudva thats is not enough information. The error is in the Logcat. Post it

Comment: Never mind, same error. I don't really get what's going on with all of the jar's and stuff, all i know is that I followed a tutorial that is not working on android. However, when i unchecked gdx-freetype.jar in all of my projects, it still worked on my desktop one @Lestat

Comment: The desktop one will work because it adds the lib when running from eclipse. (if wouldnt work if you export it as Runnable jar). Just add it to the core project.

Comment: K, i added it to the core project and removed it from the android project because that seemed to be the problem, but it is once again coming up with the same error. @Lestat

Answer (score 2):

I've struggled with that issue for almost 2 hours, but finally found exact problem. In my case I had gdx-freetype.jar in both "libs" folder and build.gradle.
But you can see, that in "core" project there is a dependency to compile jars from libs and everything else from com.badlogicgames.gdx:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: '../libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-ai:$aiVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
}
```

and in that case compiler compiles gdx-freetype twice, so we have "Multiple dex files define" error.

The solution is just to delete that jars from the libs folder.
Hope this helps!